# Has anyone used Firebase Cloud Messaging in Appcelerator?

Tags: firebase, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, firebase-cloud-messaging

Google changed his GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) to FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging). What should I do to integrate it with Appcelerator app?
I found a lot of modules in marketplace but I think they only work with GCM.

Has anyone tried to combine it?

Comment: hey kreatywny, did you solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

I have this currently working with FCM and a module called Ti.Goosh. It works really well and I can send push notifications to web browsers and Android devices with it. https://github.com/caffeinalab/ti.goosh

Comment: Receiving Firebase push notification also works for me using this great module and Titanium SDK 6.1.1

Comment: I implemented Ti.goosh in my app and i'm getting device token, but unfortunately If I sent notification from firebase, i couldn't get that in my app. Also, i couldn't find out where my firebase server key should be added to the google developer console to link my app with firebase. I created a new project in google developer console API and got a Project Number that added to the tiapp.xml. Can anyone help me pls in this regards.

Answer (score 0):

create an html with some Firebase functions, in my case we need to find some vehicles on a Geo radio

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Firebase</title>
        <!-- Firebase -->
        <script src="firebase.js"></script>
        <!-- GeoFire -->
        <script src="geofire.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="margin:0;padding:0;border:0;">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var markers = new Array();
            var markersArray = [];
            var driverInvitations;
            var diverInvited;

            Ti.App.addEventListener('firebase:init', function(e) {
                Ti.API.info('Geofire init');
                Ti.API.info(e);
                Ti.API.info('latitude :'+e.latitude);
                Ti.API.info('longitude :'+e.longitude);

                var latitude = parseFloat(e.latitude);
                var longitude = parseFloat(e.longitude);

                // Set the center
                var center = [latitude, longitude];
                // Query radius
                var radiusInKm = 0;
                // Get a reference to the Firebase public transit open data set
                var transitFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://xxx.firebaseio.com/");
                // Create a new GeoFire instance, pulling data from the public transit data
                var geoFire = new GeoFire(transitFirebaseRef.child("_geofire"));
                /*************/
                /*  GEOQUERY */
                /*************/
                // Keep track of all of the vehicles currently within the query
                var vehiclesInQuery = {};
                // Create a new GeoQuery instance
                var geoQuery = geoFire.query({
                    center : center,
                    radius : radiusInKm
                });

                geoQuery.on("ready", function() {
                  Ti.API.info("GeoQuery has loaded and fired all other events for initial data");
                  Ti.App.fireEvent('fbController:selectDriver');
                });

                /* Adds new vehicle markers to the map when they enter the query */
                geoQuery.on("key_entered", function(vehicleId, vehicleLocation) {
                    Ti.API.info('Geofire enter driver, id ' + vehicleId + ', on location ' + vehicleLocation);

                    var latitude = vehicleLocation[0];
                    var longitude = vehicleLocation[1];

                    Ti.App.fireEvent('fbController:addMarker', {
                        id : vehicleId,
                        latitude : latitude,
                        longitude : longitude
                    });

                });
                /* Moves vehicles markers on the map when their location within the query changes */
                geoQuery.on("key_moved", function(vehicleId, vehicleLocation) {
                    Ti.API.info('Geofire move driver, id ' + vehicleId + ', moved to : ' + vehicleLocation);

                    var latitude = vehicleLocation[0];
                    var longitude = vehicleLocation[1];

                    Ti.App.fireEvent('fbController:moveMarker', {
                        id : vehicleId,
                        latitude : latitude,
                        longitude : longitude
                    });

                });
                /* Removes vehicle markers from the map when they exit the query */
                geoQuery.on("key_exited", function(vehicleId) {
                    Ti.API.info('Geofire exited driver, id ' + vehicleId);

                    Ti.App.fireEvent('fbController:removeMarker', {
                        id : vehicleId
                    });
                });

            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

then on the View window we add the html to the container view

```
var webview = Ti.UI.createWebView({
    url: Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory + '/webview/firebase/index.html',
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    visible: false
});

webview.addEventListener('load', function() {
    Ti.App.fireEvent('firebase:init', {
        latitude : latitude,
        longitude : longitude
    });
});

$.container.add(webview);
```

create some events to communicate with the Firebase Webview

```
var Map = require('ti.map');
var mapview;
var annotations = [];

Ti.App.addEventListener('fbController:addMarker', function(e) {
    Ti.API.info('Firebase add marker: ' + e.id);

    annotations[e.id] = Map.createAnnotation({
        latitude: e.latitude,
        longitude: e.longitude,
        image: '/images/icon-car.png'
    });

    if (Ti.App.Properties.getBool('locationEnabled') == true) {
        mapview.addAnnotation(annotations[e.id]);
    } else {

    }
});

Ti.App.addEventListener('fbController:moveMarker', function(e) {
    Ti.API.info('Firebase move marker: ' + e.id);

    annotations[e.id].setLatitude(e.latitude);
    annotations[e.id].setLongitude(e.longitude);
});

Ti.App.addEventListener('fbController:removeMarker', function(e) {
    Ti.API.info('Firebase remove marker: ' + e.id);
    if (Ti.App.Properties.getBool('locationEnabled') == true) {
        mapview.removeAnnotation(annotations[e.id]);
        delete annotations[e.id];
    }
});
```

Anything you need can ask me, I am using this on an App and is working good, try to improving everyday but with this setup we did the job :), hope this helps, greetings

Comment: I think you are speaking about different thing. My questions is about [FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) used to deliver notifications. You speak about Firebase with Javascript API, which can be used in webview.

Comment: I realized too late :P, let me try some stuff with FCM and I'll give you feedback

Comment: Have you found any way?

Answer (score 0):

I do it as this way in my Android app:

1. Install module ln.vanvianen.android.gcm
2. Create instance in alloy.js: `var FCM = require('actions/gcm');// pub/sub`
3. In [app/lib/actions/gcm.js](https://gist.github.com/accuervo/71e48b98caa7a88bb28a7b67e0f3e6fa) create instance of module and logic to interact with fcm.
4. As I use promises on gcm.js, link bluebird library in alloy.js: `var Promise = require('bluebird/bluebird');`
5. Run my app: `appc run -p android -T device`
6. To test run CURL command or use firebase notification console: `https://console.firebase.google.com/project/your-project-name/notification` 
   [Firebase Notification Console example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6oMB.png)

Works for me with: sdk-version 5.5.0.GA